# Model inheritance and model specific code in the controller/view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance

I am using Rails single-table inheritance with a superclass Content and a number of subclasses (such as Article, Comment etc.) I am trying to get away with a single controller, and I have set up the routes thusly:

```
resources :contents
resources :articles, :controller => "contents"
resources :comments, :controller => "contents"
```

This way, `/articles/new` gets routed to `contents#new` which seems to be what I want.

Within the controller and the views, however, I need to tailor the functionality a bit depending on which actual model I am dealing with. For that purpose, I need to determine the original requested resource or otherwise find out which subclass I am dealing with.

Looking at `params` for `/articles/new`within the common controller gives `{"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"contents"}`, which obviously does not provide the information I need.

Either the answer is really obvious or I am using model inheritance wrong. Which one is it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the part of the request path you are interested in like this

```
path = request.fullpath[%r{^/(articles|comments)/}, 1] # articles or comments
```

Once you have it you can get the model class like that:

```
model_class = path.classify.constantize # Article or Comment
```

Bests,

Richard

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Further investigation showed that I can also do
`resources :comments, :controller => "contents", :type => "Comment"`
and then refer to `params[:type]`. But your solution also fits the bill and taught me `classify` and `constantize`. Thanks!